# Options on spinner based on which button clicked in Android

Tags: android

I have this layout with buttons A & B and a spinner under them.
The A & B buttons work like radio buttons. I want to make it, when the user clicks button A, the spinner shows options for example 1,2,3,4 but when the user clicks the button B, the spinner will only give 1 & 2 as the options.

Code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_game);

        Spinner spinner_player = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_player);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> a = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.player_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        a.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner_player.setAdapter(a);
        spinner_player.setSelection(1);

        ((RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio_sudoku)).setChecked(true);

    }
```

Comment: You haven't tried anything at all I think just you have initialized everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set spinner's contents in code, so nothing prevents you from changing them in response to button click. Or just create two spinners and make one hidden, and on button click change visibility of spinners.

Comment: @hectichavana you already have the code you need.  `spinner_player.setAdapter(a);` - just create two adapters and change them as needed.